# SQL How to display people with highest sum

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE.Fname,EMPLOYEE.Lname,
D.Dnumber,
SUM(WORKS_ON.HOURS) AS SUMHOUR
FROM PROJECT
INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT D ON D.Dnumber = PROJECT.Dnum
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE ON PROJECT.Dnum= EMPLOYEE.Dno
INNER JOIN WORKS_ON ON WORKS_ON.Pno = PROJECT.Pnumber
GROUP BY EMPLOYEE.Fname,EMPLOYEE.Lname, D.Dnumber
```

I'm writing a code that lists people with the highest SUMHOUR.
Now, I've found who has the biggest sum, but I can't set condition like max(sum()) for displaying them.

[image]

This is my output. In this image, people with Dnumber '5' have highest SUMHOUR '150' and I want to display them. What should I do?

Comment: provide some sample data and your expected output in table format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple approach uses `TOP`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
    e.Fname,
    e.Lname,
    d.Dnumber,
    SUM(w.HOURS) AS SUMHOUR
FROM PROJECT p
INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT d
    ON d.Dnumber = p.Dnum
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE e
    ON p.Dnum = e.Dno
INNER JOIN WORKS_ON w
    ON w.Pno = p.Pnumber
GROUP BY
    e.Fname,
    e.Lname,
    d.Dnumber
ORDER BY
    SUMHOUR DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have puted Dnumber in group by so it returns highest SUMHOUR in each Dnumber.

So sloution is just remove Dnumber from group by then it return highest SUMHOUR only.